# How to insert list of objects using ContentValues.put()?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, content-values

I am trying to insert data into the SQLite database and for that I have written a simple method to insert the data that I get from the API as shown below:

```
public static ContentValues gameInfoToContentValues(@NonNull GameInfoList game) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(GameEntry.COLUMN_GAME_ID, game.id());
        values.put(GameEntry.COLUMN_GAME_ALIASES, game.aliases());
        values.put(GameEntry.COLUMN_GAME_API_DETAIL_URL, game.api_detail_url());
        values.put(GameEntry.COLUMN_GAME_DATE_ADDED, game.date_added());
        values.put(GameEntry.COLUMN_GAME_DATE_LAST_UPDATED, game.date_last_updated());
        values.put(GameEntry.COLUMN_GAME_SMALL_IMAGE, game.image().small_url());
        values.put(GameEntry.COLUMN_GAME_MEDIUM_IMAGE, game.image().medium_url());
        values.put(GameEntry.COLUMN_GAME_HD_IMAGE, game.image().super_url());
        values.put(GameEntry.COLUMN_GAME_NAME, game.name());
        values.put(GameEntry.COLUMN_GAME_ORIGINAL_RELEASE_DATE, game.original_game_rating());

        return values;
    }
```

I am getting for the last

```
game.original_game_rating();
```

which is correctly justified because it is a List of object.

My object class named "GameInfoList" which is passed as the parameter in the method is shown below:

```
public abstract long id();

@Nullable
public abstract String aliases();

@Nullable
public abstract String api_detail_url();

@Nullable
public abstract String date_added();

@Nullable
public abstract String date_last_updated();

@Nullable
public abstract GameImages image();

@Nullable
public abstract String name();

@Nullable
public abstract List<GameRatings> original_game_rating();
```

**EDIT**

I also have GameRatings object as shown below:

```
@Nullable
public abstract String api_detail_url();

public abstract long id();

@Nullable
public abstract String name();
```

Now I want to insert the name inside the table for game rating for which I have modified the code as below:

```
public static ContentValues gameInfoToContentValues(@NonNull GameInfoList game) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    if(game.original_game_rating() != null) {
        for(GameRatings ratings : game.original_game_rating()) {
            values.put(GameEntry.COLUMN_GAME_ID, game.id());
            values.put(GameEntry.COLUMN_GAME_ALIASES, game.aliases());
            values.put(GameEntry.COLUMN_GAME_API_DETAIL_URL, game.api_detail_url());
            values.put(GameEntry.COLUMN_GAME_DATE_ADDED, game.date_added());
            values.put(GameEntry.COLUMN_GAME_DATE_LAST_UPDATED, game.date_last_updated());
            values.put(GameEntry.COLUMN_GAME_SMALL_IMAGE, game.image().small_url());
            values.put(GameEntry.COLUMN_GAME_MEDIUM_IMAGE, game.image().medium_url());
            values.put(GameEntry.COLUMN_GAME_HD_IMAGE, game.image().super_url());
            values.put(GameEntry.COLUMN_GAME_NAME, game.name());
            values.put(GameEntry.COLUMN_GAME_ORIGINAL_GAME_RATING, ratings.name());
        }
    }

    return values;
}
```

Is this right?

Comment: sqlite database only stores primitive values. you need to store it as text and the while using it you can convert it into List

Comment: What is your schema for the table you are going to insert this data into? Specifically, what is the data type of the column identified as `COLUMN_GAME_ORIGINAL_RELEASE_DATE`?

Comment: @CommonsWare The data type for COLUMN_GAME_ORIGINAL_RELEASE_DATE is TEXT

Answer (score 5):

You have two choices:

1. Get rid of that column and have `GameRatings` go in a separate table, through a 1:N relation with your `GameEntry`(?) table
2. Convert your `List<GameRatings>` into text (e.g., JSON) and store the text in the column